# I cannot enable firestore on a project although I'm not using AppEngine nor Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to activate firestore on a project on which I'm not using AppEngine nor Datastore and having this error message.

*Cannot enable Firestore for this project
Currently Firestore cannot be enabled in projects already using Cloud Datastore or App Engine*

To be more precise, I used to use datastore but now there is no entities in my project datastore. So maybe there is something that I need to disable explicitly

Thx in advance for your help

Comment: Sorry Frank but it is not. Besides when I posted my question in that feed I was asked to open a new question. thx !

Comment: Voted to reopen since it's subtly, but meaningfully, different and not really a dup. @Frank

Comment: Great ! Thank you @Frank

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately since you have previously used Cloud Datastore in that project, you cannot create a Cloud Firestore instance. Our ability to switch it currently only works if it was never used in the past.

Comment: Thank you Dan for your feedback !

Comment: Well, a Beta of anything is normal to some functionality not working out as it seems to be... Rest assure we'll wait for Stable one.

Comment: Is there any workaround for GCP support to delete the old Cloud Datastore meta trail from project entirely if no longer in use?

Comment: Yes as @vgrafe mentioned an even in a fresh project not able disable Datastore to use Firestore. Throws error like "Following service(s) depend on service(s) to be deactivated: cloudapis.googleapis.com"

Comment: I fixed it by disabling it in the GCP console then clicking create in the Firebase console. After that I got the error again but when I refreshed it was there.

Answer (score 0):

go to the **Project Settings** and add **Default GCP resource location**:

[image]

Then try to **create database**