# Unable to use Firestore for fresh projects

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

Further to [I cannot enable firestore on a project although I'm not using AppEngine nor Datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46605642), we created a couple Firebase projects and specifically went out of our way to avoid setting up AppEngine or using the Datastore — because those evidently preclude setting up Firestore — yet we get an error attempting to enable Firestore.

When we click "Create Database" in the Firebase console, we get a "Cannot enable Firebase for this project / An unknown error occurred":

[image]

In attempting to diagnose this, in Google Cloud Console, it looks like the  first AppEngine project is not set up (and it shouldn't be), speculating that perhaps the issue is with Datastore being enabled.

[image]

However, simultaneously we can "Disable application" under the App Engine => Settings:

[image]

So the question is: Why can't we enable Firestore for an effectively brand-new project?  Is it related to AppEngine?  Outside contacting support, is there a way to diagnose this?

---

Incidentally, during testing I disabled AppEngine in Google Cloud Console, and "Firebase -> Database" now states “App Engine needs to be enabled to use Cloud Firestore"

Would it be correct to assume that this is part of a transitional period for AppEngine & Firestore, and that these issues should be sorted out in the very near future?

Comment: I just created a new project and had no problems enabling Firestore on it.  If this problem is reproducible, please edit your question with the exact reproduction steps that cause the problem. Also, in general, unexpected console errors should be reported to Firebase support for investigation.  https://firebase.google.com/support/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have to touch your App Engine settings when setting up Cloud Firestore in a brand new project. In fact, there's a good chance doing so might cause inadvertent errors.

In this situation, I think your best option really is to contact customer support, since there's probably something unique to your account that's causing this issue, and the support people have the tools to diagnose it.

Answer (score 29):

This can be a problem if you have some kind of extension in your browser for handling CORS errors(while xhr requests), just like i was facing the same issue with the extension enabled. Do check it after you disable the extension.
Hopefully , it worked for me.

Comment: My Allow CORS: Access Control was enabled. This caused the error.

Comment: yes you are right I have also the same issue, I have resolved it by disabling the cors Extention

Comment: Apparently had something in my Firefox which prevented this, switching to Chrome fixed it for me...

Comment: For me it was a simple reloading the tab

Answer (score 16):

1. Disable CORS extention from the browser if you have installed one.
2. reload firebase site and click on enable button.

It will work successfully.

Comment: It worked. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

In simple terms, disable the ad-Blocker extension from firebase site.

Answer (score 5):

This is most likely related to not enabling the Firestore API for this project in the Google Cloud Platform. 
This often happens when you set up hosting for a project through the firebase CLI. 
Here's where you can enable the Firestore API: https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/google/firestore.googleapis.com?project=_

Answer (score 4):

just try to disable any CORS Extention from the browser if you have installed one.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still facing this error with ad blocker extension disabled:

Firestore is available in two modes: Native Mode & Datastore mode. [Read more](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/firestore-or-datastore?_ga=2.118697993.-1675137457.1679754609)

Mine was somehow in data-store mode and because of that, I couldn't enable firestore from firebase console.

I logged in to Google cloud platform console and switched the mode from Datastore to Native and then it worked. You might want to check which mode is active for firestore in your account.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this following below steps:

1.**Change your firesbase project mode. Check if your are running datastore mode then change it to native mode.**

you can open the propmt link to go console url

2. disable CORS from your browser and refresh it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Choose the **Native** mode as the Firestore mode in the google console.
For me the error was because I had setup the Firestore with Datastore mode earlier.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disable extensions and refresh the firebase tab. This worked for me.